# Add customer details to checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout, customer-address

I'm working on a tool that will let a customer reorder the same products as last order (pre added to cart) by clicking an unique link in e-mail.

By code I'm able to add the products to cart, however I also want to add the customer details such as firstname, lastname, company, address, email, phone etc to the checkout page.

I guess its the billing part of the checkout so its not new atttributes.

Can this be done?

Comment: please visit link:-http://www.unexpectedit.com/magento/add-new-customer-attribute-onepage-magento-checkout you give the best solustion

Comment: Its not a custom attribute. More using the existing billing values

Comment: Would this be customer attributes taken from an already existing customer? Also would it be to automatically have the checkout fields with the respective values already filled?

Comment: Actually taking det customer attributes from the existing/old order and to have the respective values filled at checkout.